# Get display length of string with smcl tags

Tags: stata

I have strings with smcl tags, for example `"{bf:{ul:opt}ion}({it:string})"`. How do I programmatically get the length of such string when it is displayed? I want to store the length in a macro.

When displayed, disregarding formatting, that string becomes `"option(string)"` which has length 14, even though the length of `"{bf:{ul:opt}ion}({it:string})"` is 29.

I could write my own parser, but that seems like a lot of work. I also need a solution that does not depend on community written commands (such as commands installed from SSC).

This is a reproducible example, that also shows what I have tried so far.

```
local str_smcl "{bf:{ul:opt}ion}({it:string})"
local str_text "option(string)"

* Display string and length of string with smcl syntax
display "`str_smcl'"
display "`=strlen("`str_smcl'")'" // returns 29
* Display string and length of string without smcl syntax
display "`str_text'"
display "`=strlen("`str_text'")'" // returns 14

* Using the display macro function
local str_text1 : display "`str_smcl'"
display "`=strlen("`str_text1'")'" // returns 29

* Commented out as Stata does not accept this syntax despite 
* helpfile stating that all features of display should work
* when using it as a macro function
//local str_text2 : display as smcl "`str_smcl'"

* This works which made me think "as smcl" would have
* worked too, but it does not generate the desired output
local str_text3 : display _asis "`str_smcl'"
display "`=strlen("`str_text3'")'" // returns 29
```

Comment: I have now also posted the same question here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1724070-get-display-length-of-string-with-smcl-tags